# Как создать масштабируемые маркеры leaflet js или альтернативу?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leafletjs

Задача простая: на карте разместить несколько svg-шек по координатам, но хотелось бы не просто изображений, а чтобы у них были свойства типа popup и какие-то event-ы leaflet-овские. Поэтому было принято решение засунуть svg-шки в качестве L.Icon/L.DivIcon прямо в маркеры, тем самым сохраняя возможность задания anchors как для popup так и для самой иконки. Только вот L.Marker ведет себя как маркер (логично) и он всегда при зуме сохраняет свой исходный размер.

Отсюда появляется следующая задача : либо отключить масштабирование у маркера КАК-ТО (я не нашел), либо искать альтернативы.

Отсюда несколько вопросов:

1. Можно ли у обычного L.Marker как-то включить пропорциональное масштабирование вместе с картой. Например, если мы рисуем L.Circle, то он масштабируется вместе с зумом - приближается отдаляется. Если обратить внимание на маркер, то он всегда сохраняет один размер. Что-то я искал и ничего не нашел.
2. Второй вопрос, можем ли мы в какой-то leaflet-овский компонент поместить svg, преследуя вышеуказанные цели?